# passing a glob expression given as a script argument to find

Tags: bash

i want find some files with given arguments in command line, this is my script

```
find -name $1
```

when i run this with argument `'*.txt'` it doesn't work. Why? What I can fix it?

Comment: Double quote the $1. Try [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: BTW, `find -name $1` also has a problem inasmuch as the ability to leave out the directory to search (ie. using this instead of `find . -name "$1"`) is a GNUism, and not portable to other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

An unquoted expansion of a wildcard is replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory that match the pattern.

Thus:

```
set -- '*.txt' # same as running your script with '*.txt' as first argument
touch a.txt b.txt c.txt

find -name $1
```

...will run:

```
find -name a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

...which isn't valid usage.

---

To avoid glob expansion, always quote your expansions: `find . -name "$1"`